# Check if ID exists in a collection with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For instance, I have a collection `User`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    googleId: String,
    facebookId: String,
    displayName: String,
    active: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And then I have an ID:

```
var userID = "some-user-id"
```

What is the right way to just check if this id exists in the `User` collection. I don't need it to read the file or return it, I just need the `true` or `false` value.

Here is one way to achieve it:

```
User.findOne({
     _id: userID
}, function (err, existingUser) {
```

**But is there faster and more efficient way?**

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use `count` rather than findOne.

This will (under the hood) cause mongoose to use `find` : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count

`findOne()` will read + return the document if it exists
On the other hand, `find()` just returns a cursor (or not) and only reads the data if you iterate over the cursor.
So in our case, we're not iterating over the cursor, merely counting the results returned.

```
User.countDocuments({_id: userID}, function (err, count){ 
    if(count>0){
        //document exists });
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually. "Under the hood" this uses the `.count()` method. Which is a specific method and is generally eh most optimal way to do so. Even though it is true that `.count()` is actually a "modifier" to a `.find()` cursor return, it is probably best to actually explain that point rather than leave it in obscurity.

Comment: `count` now triggers a warning: "DeprecationWarning: `collection.count` is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use `collection.countDocuments` or `collection.estimatedDocumentCount` instead".

Comment: Use `countDocuments()` instead

Answer (score 73):

You can now use **`User.exists()`** as of **September 2019** like so:

`const doesUserExit = await User.exists({ _id: userID });`

From the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.exists):

> Under the hood, `MyModel.exists({ answer: 42 })` is equivalent to
>   `MyModel.findOne({ answer: 42 }).select({ _id: 1 }).lean().then(doc =>
>   !!doc)`

Comment: trying to use this in a pre save hook but getting exists is not a function mongoose - 5.7.13

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is fine for small collections.

A **faster way on larger collections** is to simply use this:

```
const result = await User.findOne({ _id: userID }).select("_id").lean();
if (result) {
    // user exists...
}

// or without "async/await":

User.findOne({ _id: userID }).select("_id").lean().then(result => {
    if (result) {
        // user exists...
    }
});
```

It won't return all fields. I believe they are currently working on [a new feature](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6872) to support what you (and I) want.

---

In the meantime you could create a plugin, very simple and reusable.

Create an `any.js` file with this code:

```
module.exports = function any(schema, options) {
    schema.statics.any = async function (query) {
        const result = await this.findOne(query).select("_id").lean();
        return result ? true : false;
      };
  }
```

Then in your model you do this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const any = require('./plugins/any'); // I'm assuming you created a "plugins" folder for it

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    googleId: String,
    facebookId: String,
    displayName: String,
    active: Boolean
});

UserSchema.plugin(any);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

...and use it like this:

```
const result = await User.any({ _id: userID });
if (result) {
    // user exists...
}

// or without using "async/await":

User.any({ _id: userID }).then(result => {
    if (result) {
        // user exists...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

OR you can simply use exists function, without making any async/await:

```
myData = {_id: userID};

User.exists(myData,(error, result)=>{
    if (error){
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      console.log("result:", result)  //result is true if myData already exists
    }
  });
```

You can play with the result now!

Answer (score 0):

```
User.exists({ _id: userID }).then(exists => {
  if (exists) {
    res.redirect('/dashboard')
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
})
```

More info can be found at [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.exists).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is excellent, but I would really recommend using [estimatedDocumentCount()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-estimatedDocumentCount) if you are searching existing document by an indexed property (like _id of X).

[On the other hand, this should actually work better and is cleaner.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55427612/20458436)

Comment: p.s. I would love to add this addition to the original answers but I lack StackOverflow "reputation".
✌️

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).